# WPF DataGridTemplateColumn. Am I missing something?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, focus, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

```
     <data:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
        <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
            </DataTemplate>
        </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
        <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}">
            </DataTemplate>
        </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate> 
    </data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

It's clear example of Template column, right? What could be wrong with that? 
So, here is the thing - when a user navigates through DataGrid with hitting TAB-key, it needs to hit the TAB twice(!) to be able to edit text in TextBox. How could I make it editable as soon as the user gets the column focus, I mean even if he just starts typing?

Ok. I found a way - into Grid.KeyUp() I put the code below:

```
 if (Grid.CurrentColumn.Header.ToString() == "UserName")
        {
            if (e.Key != Key.Escape) 
            {
                Grid.BeginEdit();

                // Simply send another TAB press
                if (Keyboard.FocusedElement is Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell)
                {
                    var keyEvt = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0, Key.Tab) { RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent };
                    InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(keyEvt);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 9):

your issue stems from the fact that each cell puts its editor in a content control which first receives focus, then you have to tab once again to the editor. If you have a look at the code for DataGridTemplateColumn in the GenerateEditingElement method it calls a method LoadTemplateContent which does this:

```
private FrameworkElement LoadTemplateContent(bool isEditing, object dataItem, DataGridCell cell)
{
    DataTemplate template = ChooseCellTemplate(isEditing);
    DataTemplateSelector templateSelector = ChooseCellTemplateSelector(isEditing);
    if (template != null || templateSelector != null)
    {
        ContentPresenter contentPresenter = new ContentPresenter();
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(contentPresenter, ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, new Binding());
        contentPresenter.ContentTemplate = template;
        contentPresenter.ContentTemplateSelector = templateSelector;
        return contentPresenter;
    }

    return null;
}
```

see how it creates a new content presenter to put the template in. Other people have dealt with this problem in a variety of ways, I derive my own column type to deal with this stuff. (so i dont create an extra element or set the content presenter to not receive focus) In this [example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/93d66047-1469-4bed-8fc8-fa5f9bdd2166/) they are using focus manager to deal with the same issue (i havent tested this code)

```
<tk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <Grid FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=txt1}">
         <TextBox Name="txt1" Text="{Binding XPath=@ISBN}" 
                  BorderThickness="0" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus"/>
      </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
</tk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

If you have a user control as your editor then you can use the pattern with the focus manager or use an event handler for the OnLoaded event.

Comment: works a treat, but this is really an ugly hack... :( I wish MS would find a nice way of providing this kind of functionality

Comment: The FocusManager method works well.  In order to get the contents selected, you can also add a got focus method:

     private void StrikeTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(textBox.SelectAll));
    }

Answer (score 9):

The issue that you faced is that the control (e.g. TextBox) within the DataGridTemplateColumn is contained within a DataGridCell. By default the DataGridCell has tab-stop functionality. Thus the reason for having to hit TAB twice to get focus to your TextBox control. The solution is to disable the tab-stop functionality for the DataGridCell. This can be done via a style for the DataGridCell.

Here's the solution:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
     <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is my approach. Its very close to @Nalin Jayasuriya answer, but I didn't want to create a style. Also this solution selects the text in the TextBox. Anyway - the XAML for the hole DataGrid looks like this.

```
<DataGrid Name="TextBlockDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Rows}" Style="{StaticResource DefaultSettingsDataGrid}">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Text}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderThickness="{Binding ErrorBorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{Binding ErrorBorderBrush}">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding UserText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                             GotKeyboardFocus="TextBox_GotKeyboardFocus"
                             PreviewMouseDown="TextBox_PreviewMouseDown"
                             Style="{StaticResource DefaultTextBox}"/>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

And the code-behind.

```
private void TextBox_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ((TextBox)sender).SelectAll();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { GlobalDebug.debugForm.WriteText(ex); }
}

private void TextBox_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // If its a triple click, select all text for the user.
        if (e.ClickCount == 3)
        {
            ((TextBox)sender).SelectAll();
            return;
        }

        // Find the TextBox
        DependencyObject parent = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;
        while (parent != null && !(parent is TextBox))
        {
            parent = System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
        }

        if (parent != null)
        {
            if (parent is TextBox)
            {
                var textBox = (TextBox)parent;
                if (!textBox.IsKeyboardFocusWithin)
                {
                    // If the text box is not yet focussed, give it the focus and
                    // stop further processing of this click event.
                    textBox.Focus();
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { GlobalDebug.debugForm.WriteText(ex); }
}
```

For a more info, have a look at my blog:
http://blog.baltz.dk/post/2014/11/28/WPF-DataGrid-set-focus-and-mark-text

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to use a TriggerAction which sets the focus to the template element you want when it loads.

The trigger is very simple:

```
public class TakeFocusAndSelectTextOnVisibleBehavior : TriggerAction<TextBox>
{
    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            DispatcherPriority.Loaded,
            new Action(() =>
            {
                AssociatedObject.Focus();
                AssociatedObject.SelectAll();
            }));
    }
}
```

The DataTemplate looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Price, Mode=TwoWay}"
                MinHeight="0"
                Padding="1,0"
                Height="20">
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
            <Interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                <Behaviors:TakeFocusAndSelectTextOnVisibleBehavior />
            </Interactivity:EventTrigger>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

You can write other triggers for other element types.

Comment: I think this functionality requires a dll from Expression Blend