# WPF Stackpanel inside DataGrid Cell

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

I have got a WPF Application, which contains a Window, inside it there is a DataGrid. On Startup, the DataGrid is completely empty, its Columns are created at runtime by code.

I'm binding to a DataTable. The first coloumn is a single Text Field. I need to show one more Cell per Row, but as a Stackpanel, which itself holds some UserControls.

Actually I'm trying to first insert a blank column as placeholder for my StackPanel and later insert a StackPanel from Code to each Cell.

Unfortunately i don't get it running for some reasons. I cannot put a new Item to the Cell. Can anybody help me, please?

Best Regards,

Jonas

Comment: Please explain more, give us your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and use a `DataGridTemplateColumn`, then you can put a stackpanel in each cell

Comment: Hi,
How can I set this DataGridTemplateColumn by Code?
I found this example, but i cannot get it running:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104164/wpf-datagridtemplatecolumn-am-i-missing-something

Comment: in your xaml specify the data template <DataTemplate> and give it a Name. then in you code you get the data template by using FindResource. Then set the CellTemplate of the DataGridTemplateColumn the result.

Comment: Yeah, DataGridTemplateColumn works fine, my mistake was, that i put the DataTemplate just inside the DataGrid, and FindRessource was unable to find it there. I moved it to the Windows.Ressources Tag and it works perfect.

Another Problem i've got is, how can i access this even created StackPanel inside DataGrid by code and fill it with some Objekts?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to design and fill the datagrid via XAML.

- YourItems is the Collection of object which you want to show
- userControlColumn is the additional column for your usercontrol
- firstColumn is your first DataGridTextColumn

  ```
  <DataGrid x:Name="myGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding YourItems}">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="userControlColumn" Header="Column1">
              <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                      <StackPanel>
                          <ns:YourCustomControl/>
                      </StackPanel>
                  </DataTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn>
          <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="firstColumn" Header="Columns2" Binding="{Binding YourDesiredProperty}"/>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
  ```